# What's the simplest way to put a python script into the system tray (Windows)

Tags: python, system-tray

What's the simplest way to put a python script into the system tray?

My target platform is Windows. I don't want to see the 'cmd.exe' window.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Those are two questions, actually:

1. Adding a tray icon can be done with Win32 API. Example: [SysTrayIcon.py](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html)
2. Hiding the `cmd.exe` window is as easy as using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe` to run your scripts.

Comment: To run the SysTrayIcon demo it is necessary to put some icon files into the directory also. Search for *.ico under c:\windows and its subirectories and copy them.

Comment: I tried this. It worked. but menu_item did not show image. Eg - ('Say Hello', icons.next(), hello)
This do not show icon.

Comment: I modified `SysTrayIcon.py` to work with **Python 3** here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48775936/2441026

Comment: The only issues with this program upgrading to Python3 is that print statements need to have parentheses, each occurrence of `icons.next` needs to be changed to `next(icons)` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237611/itertools-cycle-next, and `basestring` needs to be changed to `str` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803467/unexpected-exception-name-basestring-is-not-defined-when-invoking-ansible2 Then, the code should work as expected.