# itertools.cycle().next()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools, cycle

Well, I was using `itertools.cycle().next()` method with Python 2.6.6, but now that I updated to 3.2 I noticed that `itertools.cycle()` object has no method `next()`.

I used it to cycle a string in the `spin()`method of a `Spinner` class. So if we cycle the tuple `('|', '/', '-', '\\', '|', '/', '-')`, it'll print: `|`, `/`, `-`, `\` , `|`, `/`, `-`, `|`, `/` and so on...

I've searched the release notes of Python 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2 and didn't noticed any change on this. When this have changed? Is there any simple alternative to achieve the same functionality as before?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 for this funny use case of `cycle` :)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`iter.next()` was removed in python 3. Use `next(iter)` instead. So in your example change `itertools.cycle().next()` to `next(itertools.cycle())`

There is a [good example here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#next) along with various other porting to python 3 tips. It also compares various other `next()` idioms in python 2.x vs python 3.x

Comment: You answered almost the same thing as @Sven (well, I know, it couldn't be different), but your link saved your answer. I didn't know the http://diveintopython3.org/... Bookmarked! Thanks for the answer and link. :)

Comment: Yup - we both answered at roughly the same time. Glad you found the link useful, I've found it to be a good reference.

Comment: Why was `iter.next()` removed?

Comment: @KurtMueller A trivial websearch yields the answer: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/ Don't forget to use websearch when you don't know something

Comment: The link is dead now. Any chance that anyone can find and update the link? Thanks.

Comment: The link is broken now

Answer (score 17):

In Python 3.x, iterators don't have `it.next()` any more.  use `next(it)` instead, which also works in Python 2.6 or above.  Internally, this will call `it.next()` in Python 2.x and `it.__next__()` in Python 3.x.