# unique plot marker for each plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I have a loop where i create some plots and I need unique marker for each plot. I think about creating function, which returns random symbol, and use it in my program in this way:

```
for i in xrange(len(y)):
    plt.plot(x, y [i], randomMarker())
```

but I think this way is not good one.
I need this just to distinguish plots on legend, because plots must be not connected with lines, they must be just sets of dots.

Comment: Do actually need each marker to be different, or do you just want your points to not be connected by a line?

Comment: I need  each marker to be different and want points to not be connected by lines.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`itertools.cycle` will iterate over a list or tuple indefinitely. This is preferable to a function which randomly picks markers for you.

## Python 2.x

```
import itertools
marker = itertools.cycle((',', '+', '.', 'o', '*')) 
for n in y:
    plt.plot(x,n, marker = marker.next(), linestyle='')
```

## Python 3.x

```
import itertools
marker = itertools.cycle((',', '+', '.', 'o', '*')) 
for n in y:
    plt.plot(x,n, marker = next(marker), linestyle='')
```

You can use that to produce a plot like this (Python 2.x):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

x = np.linspace(0,2,10)
y = np.sin(x)

marker = itertools.cycle((',', '+', '.', 'o', '*')) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for q,p in zip(x,y):
    ax.plot(q,p, linestyle = '', marker=marker.next())
    
plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Comment: +1'ed since this shows a nice way how this can work with an arbitrary number of plots. Same method works with colors etc.

Comment: +1 Never knew about the itertools.cycle. Much better than the half-baked lambda/modulo schemes I've used before.

Comment: Just a note for those using Python 3.x, itertools.cycle.next has been changed to next(itertools.cycle()). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237611/itertools-cycle-next

Answer (score 15):

It appears that nobody has mentioned the built-in pyplot method for cycling properties yet. So here it is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler

x = np.linspace(0,3,20)
y = np.sin(x)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(marker=['o', '+', 'x', '*', '.', 'X']) # gca()=current axis

for q,p in zip(x,y):
    plt.plot(q,p, linestyle = '')

plt.show()
```

[image: Marker cycle only]

However, this way you lose the color cycle. You can add back color by multiplying or adding a color `cycler` and a marker `cycler` object, like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()

markercycle = cycler(marker=['o', '+', 'x', '*', '.', 'X'])
colorcycle = cycler(color=['blue', 'orange', 'green', 'magenta'])
# Or use the default color cycle:
# colorcycle = cycler(color=plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])

plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(colorcycle * markercycle) # gca()=current axis

for q,p in zip(x,y):
    plt.plot(q,p, linestyle = '')

plt.show()
```

[image: Marker and color cycle combined by multiplication]

When adding cycles, they need to have the same length, so we only use the first four elements of `markercycle` in that case:

```
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(colorcycle + markercycle[:4]) # gca()=current axis
```

[image: Marker and color cycle combined by addition]

Comment: It seems that one does not need to import the `cycler` module and can instead use `plt.cycler` for the same purpose. E.g. `mycyler = plt.cycler(marker=['o', '+'], color=['blue', 'orange'])` and then use it in the `set_prop_cycle()` method as usual.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that on can also "add" cyclers to get a cycler which changes multiple properties aech time.

Comment: @PaulG. Feel free to add an example, if you like.

Comment: @Fritz As my own answer? I think yours is good enough. I just think adding them is an important feature for creating plots that work for colorblind people or when printed in grayscale. If you need to multiply cyclers to get enough different styles, chances are high that you are trying to put too much information into one plot ;)

Comment: @PaulG. I meant as an edit. I try to follow Wikipedia's 'Be Bold' policy when improving posts (just making the improvement myself instead of suggesting it).

Comment: @Fritz While I like the idea (and have added an edit), I don't want to figure out your matplotlibrc. Therefore my example looks different and you might want to redo it. Should I just have redone all pictures? :D

Comment: @PaulG. That's great. No need for perfectionism here. :-)

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting, this feature does NOT work with scatter() and markers (see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15105) There have been no updates since 2021 suggesting this has been fixed or that anyone plans to fix it because of risk to the API.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use marker generation by tuple e.g. as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
markers = [(i,j,0) for i in range(2,10) for j in range(1, 3)]
[plt.plot(i, 0, marker = markers[i], ms=10) for i in range(16)]
```

See [Matplotlib markers doc site](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) for details.

In addition, this can be combined with itertools.cycle looping mentioned above

Comment: I like this answer because it allows you to increase the diversity of the markers by increasing the number in the range. Nevertheless, it is not working in v2.0.2 as the first number is the triple should be integer: `(numsides, style, angle)`. I would correct to: `n = 16` and `markers = [(2+i, 1+i%2, i/n*90.0) for i in range(1, n)]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
markers=['^', 's', 'p', 'h', '8']
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], c='green', marker=markers[i])
    plt.xlabel('X Label')
    plt.ylabel('Y Label') 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. 
This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.

Answer (score -1):

Just manually create an array that contains marker characters and use that, e.g.:

```
 markers=[',', '+', '-', '.', 'o', '*']
```

Comment: Hm, how do you exactly "use that"? When I try `ax.plot(t,s, marker=['s', 'o'], ...)`, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: This is similar to the ideas above, i.e. cycling over a predefined predefined list. I was not suggesting it can be supplied as a flag to plot().