# Set varying marker color with matplotlib plot

Tags: matplotlib

In `matplotlib`, I can have a scatter plot with varying marker color given in `clist`.
Note: the size of `clist` is the same as `ydata`, i.e., the color of each marker is specified separately.

```
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, marker='o', c=clist)
```

**Can I have something similar with `plt.plot`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to

```
plt.scatter(xdata, ydata, marker='o', c=clist)
```

would be

```
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler("color", clist))
plt.plot(np.atleast_2d(xdata), np.atleast_2d(ydata), marker="o")
```

Of course you can also use a loop. And in general, I would recommend just staying with `scatter` in such case.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution based on the trick shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13092467/4932316) for marker.

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = itertools.cycle(('r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'k')) 

for n in range(5):
    plt.plot(n, n**2, marker = 'o', color=next(colors), linestyle='')
```

[image]

Comment: The size of `clist` is the same as `ydata`, i.e., the color of each marker is specified separately.
Will this work if I use my `clist` instead of your `colors`?
Would this have a reasonable performance for, say, thousands of data points?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonica : It should work if you replace `('r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'k')` by your list in the same `(....)` format. For the performance, I would simply use `%timeit` to measure the timings

Comment: [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) accepts for `c`:
1) A single color format string.
2) A sequence of color specifications of length n.
3) A sequence of n numbers to be mapped to colors using cmap and norm.
4) A 2-D array in which the rows are RGB or RGBA.
while [`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) accepts for `color` "any matplotlib color".
Would this be the same? Or should I convert before my `clist` (which will be, mainly, a list of `float`s)?