# Y-axis values cuts off using seaborn scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have an issue with plotting the big CSV file with Y-axis values ranging from 1 upto 20+ millions. There are two problems I am facing right now.

1. The Y-axis do not show all the values that it is suppose to. When using the original data, it shows upto 6 million, instead of showing all the data upto 20 millions. In the sample data (smaller data) I put below, it only shows the first Y-axis value and does not show any other values.
2. In the label section, since I am using hue and style = name, "name" appears as the label title and as an item inside.

***Questions:***

1. Could anyone give me a sample or help me to answer how may I show all the Y-axis values? How can I fix it so all the Y-values show up?
2. How can I get rid of "name" under label section without getting rid of shapes and colors for the scatter points?

*(Please let me know of any sources exist or this question was answered on some other post without labeling it duplicated. Please also let me know if I have any grammar/spelling issues that I need to fix. Thank you!)*

***Below you can find the function I am using to plot the graph and the sample data.***

```
def test_graph (file_name):

    data_file = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None, error_bad_lines=False, delimiter="|", index_col = False, dtype='unicode')
    data_file.rename(columns={0: 'name',
                              1: 'date',
                              2: 'name3',
                              3: 'name4',
                              4: 'name5',
                              5: 'ID',
                              6: 'counter'}, inplace=True)

    data_file.date = pd.to_datetime(data_file['date'], unit='s')
    
    norm = plt.Normalize(1,4)
    cmap = plt.cm.tab10

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_file)
 
    # Below creates and returns a dictionary of category-point combinations,
    # by cycling over the marker points specified.   
    points = ['o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', '8', 's', 'p', 'H', 'D', 'd', 'P', 'X']
    mult = len(df['name']) // len(points) + (len(df['name']) % len(points) > 0)
    markers = {key:value for (key, value)
               in zip(df['name'], points * mult)} ; markers
   
    sc = sns.scatterplot(data = df, x=df['date'], y=df['counter'], hue = df['name'], style = df['name'], markers = markers, s=50)
    ax.set_autoscaley_on(True)             
    
    ax.set_title("TEST", size = 12, zorder=0)      
            
    plt.legend(title="Names", loc='center left', shadow=True, edgecolor = 'grey', handletextpad = 0.1, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))             
               
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))               
               
    plt.xlabel("Dates", fontsize = 12, labelpad = 7)
    plt.ylabel("Counter", fontsize = 12)
    plt.grid(axis='y', color='0.95')
    
    fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation = 30)     
              
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15),dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)                
test_graph(file_name)

plt.savefig(graph_results + "/Test.png", dpi=100)               

# Prevents to cut-off the bottom labels (manually) => makes the bottom part bigger
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
plt.show()
```

***Sample data***

```
namet1|1582334815|ai1|ai1||150|101
namet1|1582392415|ai2|ai2||142|105
namet2|1582882105|pc1|pc1||1|106
namet2|1582594106|pc1|pc1||1|123
namet2|1580592505|pc1|pc1||1|141
namet2|1580909305|pc1|pc1||1|144
namet3|1581974872|ai3|ai3||140|169
namet1|1581211616|ai4|ai4||134|173
namet2|1582550907|pc1|pc1||1|179
namet2|1582608505|pc1|pc1||1|185
namet4|1581355640|ai5|ai5|bcu|180|298466
namet4|1582651641|pc2|pc2||233|298670
namet5|1582406860|ai6|ai6|bcu|179|298977
namet5|1580563661|pc2|pc2||233|299406
namet6|1581283626|qe1|q0/1|Link to btse1/3|51|299990
namet7|1581643672|ai5|ai5|bcu|180|300046
namet4|1581758842|ai6|ai6|bcu|179|300061
namet6|1581298027|qe2|q0/2|Link to btse|52|300064
namet1|1582680415|pc2|pc2||233|300461
namet6|1581744427|pc3|p90|Link to btsi3a4|55|6215663
namet6|1581730026|pc3|p90|Link to btsi3a4|55|6573348
namet6|1582190826|qe2|q0/2|Link to btse|52|6706378
namet6|1582190826|qe1|q0/1|Link to btse1/3|51|6788568
namet1|1581974815|pc2|pc2||233|6895836
namet4|1581974841|pc2|pc2||233|7874504
namet6|1582176427|qe1|q0/1|Link to btse1/3|51|9497687
namet6|1582176427|qe2|q0/2|Link to btse|52|9529133
namet7|1581974872|pc2|pc2||233|9573450
namet6|1582162027|pc3|p90|Link to btsi3a4|55|9819491
namet6|1582190826|pc3|p90|Link to btsi3a4|55|13494946
namet6|1582176427|pc3|p90|Link to btsi3a4|55|19026820
```

***Results I am getting:***

***Big data:***
[image: Big-data-results]

***Small data:***
[image: Small-data-results]

***Updated Graph***
[Updated-graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oiTq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, some improvements on your post: you are missing the import statements

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import seaborn as sns
```

The line

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_file)
```

is not necessary, since `data_file` already is a DataFrame. The lines

```
points = ['o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', '8', 's', 'p', 'H', 'D', 'd', 'P', 'X']
mult = len(df['name']) // len(points) + (len(df['name']) % len(points) > 0)
markers = {key:value for (key, value)
           in zip(df['name'], points * mult)}
```

do not cycle through `points` as you might expect, maybe use `itertools` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091649/unique-plot-marker-for-each-plot-in-matplotlib). Also, setting yticks like

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))
```

for every 100 might be too much if your data is spanning values from 0 to 20 million, consider replacing 100 with, say, 1000000.

I was able to reproduce your first problem. Using `df.dtypes` I found that the column `counter` was stored as type `object`. Adding the line

```
df['counter']=df['counter'].astype(int)
```

resolved your first problem for me. I couldn't reproduce your second issue, though. Here is what the resulting plot looks like for me:
[image]
Have you tried updating all your packages to the latest version?

---

**EDIT:** as follow up on your comment, you can also adjust the number of xticks in your plot by replacing 1 in

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

by a higher number, say 10. Incorporating all my suggestions and deleting the seemingly unnecessary function definition, my version of your code looks as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import seaborn as sns
import itertools

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot()

df = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv',
    header          = None,
    error_bad_lines = False,
    delimiter       = "|",
    index_col       = False,
    dtype           = 'unicode')
df.rename(columns={0: 'name',
                   1: 'date',
                   2: 'name3',
                   3: 'name4',
                   4: 'name5',
                   5: 'ID',
                   6: 'counter'}, inplace=True)

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
df['counter'] = df['counter'].astype(int)

points  = ['o', 'v', '^', '<', '>', '8', 's', 'p', 'H', 'D', 'd', 'P', 'X']
markers = itertools.cycle(points) 
markers = list(itertools.islice(markers, len(df['name'].unique())))

sc = sns.scatterplot(
    data    = df,
    x       = 'date',
    y       = 'counter',
    hue     = 'name',
    style   = 'name',
    markers = markers,
    s       = 50)           

ax.set_title("TEST", size = 12, zorder=0)             
ax.legend(
    title          = "Names",
    loc            = 'center left',
    shadow         = True,
    edgecolor      = 'grey',
    handletextpad  = 0.1,
    bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.5))             
           
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(10))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1000000))             
ax.minorticks_off()
      
ax.set_xlabel("Dates", fontsize = 12, labelpad = 7)
ax.set_ylabel("Counter", fontsize = 12)
ax.grid(axis='y', color='0.95')

fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation = 30)  
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)   
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Appreciate your time and help. Sorry, I have the imports in my original doc, just forgot to put them in. Thanks for mentioning  them. 

After applying the changes you have mentioned (besides the markers), I receive the correct Y values (with 10^7 as seem on your graph. Problem appears now is the X-axis values are overlapping, since there are so many of them and creates a black mark across the X-axis. Please see the updated graph above for reference. How may I resolve that issue? Could you please paste your produced code as well for reference?Thanks again!

Comment: If my response resolved your issues, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Hello @Alperino. Your response helped me a lot. The x-axis looks good, but, somehow, the dates it shows go as early as the 2000s. I think there may be an issue with DateTime, but not sure. According to my data, the dates have to be 2021 when converting. Conversion is correct, but I think when plotting, it sees it as general DateTime or something that I do not understand. Do you know what could cause the issue? Any idea how may I resolve it?

Thanks again for your support and time!

Comment: There are too many possible reasons for this to be solved within a comment. Also, we now are talking about issues that are beyond what you originally asked for. I suggest you set up a minimal working example including data that causes the issue and open up a new, separate post.