# Get matplotlib color cycle state

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to query the current state of the matplotlib color cycle? In other words is there a function `get_cycle_state` that will behave in the following way?

```
>>> plot(x1, y1)
>>> plot(x2, y2)
>>> state = get_cycle_state()
>>> print state
2
```

Where I expect the state to be the index of the next color that will be used in a plot. Alternatively, if it returned the next color ("r" for the default cycle in the example above),  that would be fine too.

Comment: This can be done, even without changing the current state, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442719/2707864)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

#### Accessing the color cycle iterator

There's no "user-facing" (a.k.a. "public") method to access the underlying iterator, but you can access it through "private" (by convention) methods.  However, you'd can't get the state of an `iterator` without changing it.

#### Setting the color cycle

Quick aside: You can set the color/property cycle in a variety of ways (e.g. `ax.set_color_cycle` in versions <1.5 or `ax.set_prop_cycler` in >=1.5).  Have a look at the [example here for version 1.5 or greater](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html), or the [previous style here](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html).

#### Accessing the underlying iterator

However, while there's no public-facing method to access the iterable, you can access it for a given axes object (`ax`) through the `_get_lines` helper class instance.  `ax._get_lines` is a touch confusingly named, but it's the behind-the-scenes machinery that allows the `plot` command to process all of the odd and varied ways that `plot` can be called.  Among other things, it's what keeps track of what colors to automatically assign. Similarly, there's `ax._get_patches_for_fill` to control cycling through default fill colors and patch properties.

At any rate, the color cycle iterable is `ax._get_lines.color_cycle` for lines and `ax._get_patches_for_fill.color_cycle` for patches.  On matplotlib >=1.5, this has changed to [use the `cycler` library](http://matplotlib.org/cycler/), and the iterable is called `prop_cycler` instead of `color_cycle` and yields a `dict` of properties instead of only a color.

All in all, you'd do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
color_cycle = ax._get_lines.color_cycle
# or ax._get_lines.prop_cycler on version >= 1.5
# Note that prop_cycler cycles over dicts, so you'll want next(cycle)['color']
```

#### You can't view the state of an `iterator`

However, this object is a "bare" `iterator`. We can easily get the next item (e.g. `next_color = next(color_cycle)`, but that means that the next color *after that* is what will be plotted.  By design, there's no way to get the current state of an iterator without changing it.

In `v1.5` or greater, it would be nice to get the `cycler` object that's used, as we could infer its current state. However, the `cycler` object itself isn't accessible (publicly or privately) anywhere. Instead, only the `itertools.cycle` instance created from the `cycler` object is accessible.  Either way, there's no way to get to the underlying state of the color/property cycler.

#### Match the color of the previously plotted item instead

In your case, it sounds like you're wanting to match the color of something that was just plotted.  Instead of trying to determine what the color/property will be, set the color/etc of your new item based on the properties of what's plotted.

For example, in the case you described, I'd do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def custom_plot(x, y, **kwargs):
    ax = kwargs.pop('ax', plt.gca())
    base_line, = ax.plot(x, y, **kwargs)
    ax.fill_between(x, 0.9*y, 1.1*y, facecolor=base_line.get_color(), alpha=0.5)

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
custom_plot(x, x)
custom_plot(x, 2*x)
custom_plot(x, -x, color='yellow', lw=3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

It's not the only way, but its cleaner than trying to get the color of the plotted line before-hand, in this case.

Comment: I'm writing some higher-level functions to automate common plotting tasks for my domain of work. Often these entail drawing multiple matplotlib objects, and I'd like to have the several objects share a color in the color cycle, so I don't always have to provide a color argument if I am feeling lazy.

Comment: For example, I have a function that takes 2D data with the dimensions corresponding to (observations, time) and draws a timecourse line (representing the mean over observations) and shaded error bands (representing the variance over observations). I'd like those to be the same color.

Comment: If you're just wanting to match the color of a particular object, you can always grab its color.  e.g. `line, = ax.plot(x, y)` and then use `line.get_color()` to get the color of the previously-plotted line.

Comment: Sure, the problem is that sometimes I _do_ want to be able to specify a color for these things, so my function takes a color=None argument, but passing  None to the color argument for maplotlob raises an exception. So I need to be able to know what color I'm going to use before I plot the first thing.

Comment: If you don't mind using `**kwargs`, it makes things much cleaner, in this case. Also, if you decide later that you want to specify another property (e.g. linewidth) that you didn't originally explicitly code in, it allows everything to be passed on to `plot`. I like to add the ability to explicitly specify an axes object to plot on when I write similar functions, so I usually do something along the lines of `ax = kwargs.pop('ax', plt.gca())`.

Comment: It seems `ax._get_lines.color_cycle` no longer exists in 1.5?

Comment: @endolith - Yeah, they've changed the cycle mechanism to use Tom's new `cycler` library. It allows much more flexible style cycling. Offhand, I don't remember what the equivalent is, and I'm traveling without a laptop. If you find it, feel free to edit the question. I'll try to update it later, if I don't forget.

Comment: I think the (near) equivalent is an iterable `ax._get_lines.prop_cycler` you can have a construct something like `if 'color' in ax._get_lines._prop_keys:` followed by `next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']` to do the equivalent of what is suggested with `color_cycle` in the answer, I believe.  I'm not sure whether you can get an iterable of just the colors, I'd need to explore more.

Comment: @endolith Sure (and thanks) - but I just felt it would be better sitting in Joe's already very good and accepted answer.  If he doesn't get round to putting it in by Monday - I'll stick a proper answer up there instead of the dreaded "answer-in-comments"

Comment: for matplotlib <1.5, to get the next color from the iteratore use built-in function `next()` on the iterator `ax._get_lines.color_cycle` --> `next_color = next(ax._get_lines.color_cycle)`.

Comment: @JoeKington, Could you update for Matplotlib 3.8 which removes those?

Answer (score 44):

Here's a way that works in 1.5 which will hopefully be future-proof as it doesn't rely on methods prepended with underscores:

```
colors = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"]
```

This will give you a list of the colors defined in order for the present style.

Comment: Works in 2.0.2.

Comment: This is what I required, thank you. Works in matplotlib 3.4.3.

Comment: Works in matplotlib 3.5.2

Answer (score 20):

Note: In the latest versions of matplotlib (>= 1.5) `_get_lines` has changed. You now need to use `next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']` in Python 2 or 3 (or `ax._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()['color']` in [Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237611/itertools-cycle-next)) to get the next color from the color cycle.

Wherever possible use the more direct approach shown in the lower part of @joe-kington's answer. As `_get_lines` is not API-facing it might change again in a not backward compatible manner in the future.

Comment: How do you avoid that querying the next element of the color cycler changes the cycler's state?

Answer (score 6):

Sure, this will do it.

```
#rainbow

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
ax= plt.subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot(np.sin(x))
ax.plot(np.cos(x))

rainbow = ax._get_lines.color_cycle
print rainbow
for i, color in enumerate(rainbow):
    if i<10:
        print color,
```

Gives:

```
<itertools.cycle object at 0x034CB288>
r c m y k b g r c m
```

Here is the itertools function that matplotlib uses [itertools.cycle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

Edit: Thanks for the comment, it seems that it is not possible to copy an iterator. An idea would be to dump a full cycle and keep track of which value you are using, let me get back on that.

Edit2: Allright, this will give you the next color and make a new iterator that behaves as if next was not called. This does not preserve the order of coloring, just the next color value, I leave that to you.

This gives the following output, notice that steepness in the plot corresponds to index, eg first g is the bottomest graph and so on.

```
#rainbow

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
import itertools

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi)
ax= plt.subplot(1,1,1)


def create_rainbow():
    rainbow = [ax._get_lines.color_cycle.next()]
    while True:
        nextval = ax._get_lines.color_cycle.next()
        if nextval not in rainbow:
            rainbow.append(nextval)
        else:
            return rainbow

def next_color(axis_handle=ax):
    rainbow = create_rainbow()
    double_rainbow = collections.deque(rainbow)
    nextval = ax._get_lines.color_cycle.next()
    double_rainbow.rotate(-1)
    return nextval, itertools.cycle(double_rainbow)


for i in range(1,10):
    nextval, ax._get_lines.color_cycle = next_color(ax)
    print "Next color is: ", nextval
    ax.plot(i*(x))


plt.savefig("SO_rotate_color.png")
plt.show()
```

Console

```
Next color is:  g
Next color is:  c
Next color is:  y
Next color is:  b
Next color is:  r
Next color is:  m
Next color is:  k
Next color is:  g
Next color is:  c
```

[image: Rotate color]

Comment: Thanks!  Just to clarify, it doesn't look like that returns a copy, but rather a reference to the actual cycle. So, calling rainbow.next() is actually going to change what the next plot will look like, too.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add onto what @Andi said above. Since `color_cycle` is deprecated in matplotlib 1.5, you have to use `prop_cycler`, however, Andi's solution (`ax._get_lines.prop_cycler.next()['color']`)  returned this error for me:

> AttributeError: 'itertools.cycle' object has no attribute 'next'

The code that worked for me was: `next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)`, which actually isn't far off from @joe-kington's original response.

Personally, I ran into this problem when making a twinx() axis, which reset the color cycler. I needed a way to make the colors cycle correctly because I was using `style.use('ggplot')`. There might be an easier/better way to do this, so feel free to correct me.

Comment: please format your post as an **answer**, not as a discussion material (otherwise it is a comment), your main point being that `next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)` is a possible alternative.

Comment: @Carson How do you avoid that the call `next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)` actually changes the state of the color cycler?

Comment: That's actually what I was attempting to do -- change the state of the `prop_cycler`. If you read the accepted answer to this question, you'll see that there's no way to access the state of `prop_cycler` without changing its state because it's an iterable.

Comment: The error you point out is a Python 2 / Python 3 difference. Thanks for pointing this out, I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Since matplotlib uses `itertools.cycle` we can actually look through the entire color cycle and then restore the iterator to its previous state:

```
def list_from_cycle(cycle):
    first = next(cycle)
    result = [first]
    for current in cycle:
        if current == first:
            break
        result.append(current)

    # Reset iterator state:
    for current in cycle:
        if current == result[-1]:
            break
    return result
```

This should return the list without changing the state of the iterator.

Use it with matplotlib >= 1.5:

```
>>> list_from_cycle(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)
[{'color': 'r'}, {'color': 'g'}, {'color': 'b'}]
```

or with matplotlib < 1.5:

```
>>> list_from_cycle(ax._get_lines.color_cycle)
['r', 'g', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way possible I could find without doing the whole loop through the cycler is `ax1.lines[-1].get_color()`.

Answer (score 0):

In matplotlib version 2.2.3 there is a `get_next_color()` method on the `_get_lines` property:

```
import from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
next_color = ax._get_lines.get_next_color()
```

`get_next_color()` returns an html color string, and advances the color cycle iterator.

Answer (score 0):

**How to access the color (and complete style) cycle?**

The current state is stored in `ax._get_lines.prop_cycler`.
There are no built-in methods to expose the "base list" for a generic [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), and in particular for `ax._get_lines.prop_cycler` (see below).

I have posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442656/2707864) a few functions to get info on a `itertools.cycle`.
One could then use

```
style_cycle = ax._get_lines.prop_cycler
curr_style = get_cycle_state(style_cycle)  # <-- my (non-builtin) function
curr_color = curr_style['color']
```

to get the current color **without changing the state of the cycle**.

---

**TL;DR**

**Where is the color (and complete style) cycle stored?**

The style cycle is stored in two different places, one for the *default*, and one for the *current* axes (assuming `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `ax` is an axis handler):

```
default_prop_cycler = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle']
current_prop_cycle = ax._get_lines.prop_cycler
```

Note these have different classes.
The default is a "base cycle setting" and it does not know about any current state for any axes, while the current knows about the cycle to follow and its current state:

```
print('type(default_prop_cycler) =', type(default_prop_cycler))
print('type(current_prop_cycle) =', type(current_prop_cycle))

[]: type(default_prop_cycler) = <class 'cycler.Cycler'>
[]: type(current_prop_cycle) = <class 'itertools.cycle'>
```

The default cycle may have several keys (properties) to cycle, and one can get only the colors:

```
print('default_prop_cycler.keys =', default_prop_cycler.keys)
default_prop_cycler2 = plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()
print(default_prop_cycler2)
print('colors =', default_prop_cycler2['color'])

[]: default_prop_cycler.keys = {'color', 'linestyle'}
[]: {'color': ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y'], 'linestyle': ['-', '--', ':', '-.']}
[]: colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'y']
```

One could even change the `cycler` to use for a given `axes`, after defining that `custom_prop_cycler`, with

```
ax.set_prop_cycle(custom_prop_cycler)
```

But there are no built-in methods to expose the "base list" for a generic `itertools.cycle`, and in particular for `ax._get_lines.prop_cycler`.

Answer (score -1):

## minimal working example

I struggelt with this quite a few times already.
This is a minimal working example for [Andis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33608574/7128154).
[image]

### code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


xs = np.arange(10)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for ii in range(3):
    color = next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']
    lbl = 'line {:d}, color {:}'.format(ii, color)
    ys = np.random.rand(len(xs))
    ax.plot(xs, ys, color=color, label=lbl)
ax.legend()
```