# matplotlib colororder and twinx

Tags: python, matplotlib

I adjusted the colororder for my plot by `rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = [some nice and carefully chosen colours]`

But when I use twinx for a second axes the colororder is reset:

```
 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 from matplotlib import rcParams
 rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r','g','k']
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
 ax1 = plt.twinx(ax) 
 ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
 ax.plot([1,2,3],[7,6,4])
 ax1.plot([1,2,3],[5,3,1])
```

Is there a way to circumvent that? The line plotted on `ax1` should be black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to advance the color-order for the second axis.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams

rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['r','g','k']
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1 = plt.twinx(ax) 

line = []

line.append(ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])[0])
line.append(ax.plot([1,2,3],[7,6,4])[0])

for advance in range(len(line)):
    ax1._get_lines.color_cycle.next()

ax1.plot([1,2,3],[5,3,1])
```

If you run this example, the line on the second axis will be black.

---

What happens is this:

- In `line` you keep track of the numer of lines that you have plotted on the first axis. Note, that you need to only append the first entry of the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D object`, hence the `[0]` at the end of `ax.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])`
- The `for`-loop may look a bit clumsy. However, it advances your color-cycle of the second axis by the number of lines you already have on the first axis. This is done through calling `next()` on `ax1._get_lines.color_cycle`
- You don't acutally need the loop counter `advance`, however, it makes the code more readable.
- Now, any lines on the second axis will continue with the next color in the cycle after the one you left off with on the first axis.
- If you wanted to go back to the first axis, you'd have to count the number of lines on `ax1`, too.

---

An interesting question to read in this context is: [Get Matplotlib Color Cycle State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831549/get-matplotlib-color-cycle-state)

Comment: You're welcome! Thank you for providing a good minimal working example in your question!

Answer (score 14):

Instead of advancing the color cycler of the second axis (as suggested in other answers) you can actually use a single color cycler for both axes:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(...)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler
ax2.plot(...)
```

Comment: This was discontinued. Now use ```ax2._get_lines = ax1._get_lines```. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/19479 . You might also want to do the same for ```_get_patches_for_fill```

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in [a more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34295527) to [Get Matplotlib Color Cycle State](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13831549), with matplotlib 1.5 there have been changes to color cycling related to a new, more generic "property cycling" feature. The key command in Schorsch's answer now has to be `next(ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler)`.

The strategy still involves poking around behind the scenes, so no guarantee that this also won't break in future versions.