# Cycle colors when plotting in matplotlib: Tracking state on a per-instance basis

Tags: python, matplotlib, closures

I'm trying to build a simple state-tracking function for an Axes instance in Matplotlib. Every time I create a new axes object (either directly or through other functions like `subplots()`), I want the instance to have a bound method, `a.next_color()`, that I can use to cycle through colors as I create new lines to add to the axes. I wrote something like this:

```
def set_color_sequence(colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y']):
    i = [0]
    def cf(self):
        i[0] += 1
        return colors[(i[0]-1) % len(colors)]
    return cf
```

And thought I was being clever by adding it to the parent class:

```
plt.Axes.next_color = set_color_sequence()
```

**The problem** is that the state variable `i` seems to be shared by *all* `Axes` instances, instead of each new instance having its own state. What's an elegant way to ensure that all new instances have their own state tracking function? (BTW, I'd like to do this without modifying the original matplotlib code.)

Comment: You could subclass it?  `class MyAxes(plt.Axes): def next_color(self): ...`

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831549/get-matplotlib-color-cycle-state) will help? Also, why not create a separate object / function instead of attaching a method that you need to call manually (assuming you don't modify the class further)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AMacK's comment led me to a simple solution:

```
def next_color(self):
    return next(self._get_lines.color_cycle)
plt.Axes.next_color = next_color
```

This doesn't have the custom color-sequence behavior I outline above, but it does get the per-instance behavior I was looking for in code that is terse and intelligible. (Presumably I could directly override the color_cycle iterator if I wanted to generate a custom sequence.)

Comment: OK, fair enough, but why not just call `self._get_lines.color_cycle.next()` directly? Also, whilst you can override `color_cycle`, remember that you'll either have to do it on a per-instance basis (or else subclass `plt.Axes`) in order for each instance to have its own state.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing function **will** work provided you assign the `next_color` attribute to an
**instance** of `Axes` rather than the class itself.

First of all, with
`set_color_sequence` you are basically implementing a
[generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/1461210) in a roundabout way. To
simplify things, we can achieve the same thing in one line using
`itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle
...
axes_instance.next_color = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y']).next
```

In fact, this is the way that matplotlib keeps track of where it is in the color
cycle. For example, if you take a look at an instance of
`matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` you will see that it has the attribute
`_get_lines.color_cycle`, which is an `itertools.cycle` (try calling
`color_cycle.next()`).

Now take a look at these two examples:

```
class MyClass1(object):

    # next_color is an attribute of the *class itself*
    next_color = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y']).next


class MyClass2(object):

    def __init__(self):

        # next_color is an attribute of *this instance* of the class
        self.next_color = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y']).next
```

In the first case, what happens is that the assignment

```
next_color = cycle(['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y]).next
```

gets evaluated once and only once, when the class is first imported. This means
that whenever you create a new instance of `MyClass1`, its `next_color`
attribute will point at the exact same `itertools.cycle` instance, and
therefore all instances of `MyClass1` will share a common state:

```
a = MyClass1()
b = MyClass1()

print a.next_color is b.next_color
# True

print a.next_color(), a.next_color(), b.next_color()
#  r g b
```

However, the `__init__` method gets called again and again whenever a new
*instance* of the class is being created. As a consequence, every instance of `MyClass2` gets
its own `itertools.cycle`, and therefore its own state:

```
a = MyClass2()
b = MyClass2()

print a.next_color is b.next_color
# False

print a.next_color(), a.next_color(), b.next_color()
# r g r
```

If your goal is to subclass `plt.Axes`, you need to put your assignment
somewhere where it will get called by each new instance of your subclass
(probably in `__init__`). However, if you just want to add this
method to an existing instance then literally all you need to do is:

```
axes_instance.next_color = get_color_sequence()
```

Comment: Thanks for elucidating the issues here. Accepting this answer because it provides two great strategies -- subclassing and assigning per instance. I went with the strategy in my answer because (a) it's more terse and (b) can be applied in a quick setup script and never thought about again.

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib` already has something like this. Given `ax1` an instance of `AxesSubplot` (or anything that derives `Axes`), you can access the line properties using `_get_lines`. This includes the `prop_cycler`, which can be overwritten using:

```
ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler
```

For example:

```
# Generate some data
x = linspace(-10, 10)
y_lin = 2*x
y_quad = x**2

# Create empty axes
_, ax1 = subplots()

# Plot linear
l1 = ax1.plot(y_lin)
ax1.set_ylabel('linear', color=l1[0].get_color())
ax1.tick_params('y', colors=l1[0].get_color())

# Generate secondary y-axis
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
# Make sure that plots on ax2 continue color cycle
ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler

# Plot quadratic
l2 = ax2.plot(y_quad)
ax2.set_ylabel('quadratic', color=l2[0].get_color())
ax2.tick_params('y', colors=l2[0].get_color())
```

Which outputs:

[image: Matplotlib output after copying <code>prop_cycler</code> state]

Leaving out `ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler` gets us:

[image: Matplotlib output without copying `prop_cycler]

Note: If you work within jupyter (or nteract) using the `%pylab inline` magic (so so you won't have direct access to the `matplotlib.pyplot` module). So something like `plt.Axes` is a little cumbersome.