# Plot multiple lines at once, but all according to the current cycler state

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot three lines in one go, matplotlib samples through three steps of the current cycler, giving each its own style:

```
In [11]: x = linspace(0, 5, 50)

In [12]: y = vstack([x**2, x**3, x**4]).T

In [13]: plot(x, y)
Out[13]: 
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7edfa9144550>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7edfa9144b38>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7edfa9144cf8>]
```

I can make them all the same color with `plot(x, y, color="black")`.  However, I don't want them all black; I want that each of the lines respects the current (next) state of the cycle.

Getting the [current state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13831549/974555) is cumbersome at best.  I could expand `x` and flatten `y` to get all three with the same style:

```
In [54]: plot(vstack([x]*3).ravel(), y.T.ravel())
```

but this will create a spurious line connecting the three, so it only works with plot-styles that draw marks but not lines.

Is there a pleasant way to tell matplotlib that I would like to use the same cycle state to draw multiple lines?

Answer (score 2):

Here via getting the current state:  (Not pleasant, but not too cumbersome.)

```
In [94]: plt.plot(x, y[:,1:], c=plt.plot(x, y[:,0])[0].get_c())
```

Comment: Creative!  This also provides a solution for a different challenge, which is how to get the correct legend entries when using `label=x`.