# Getting python's itertools cycle current element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know you can use `c = cycle(['a', 'b', 'c'])` to cycle between the elements using `c.next()`, but is there away to get the iterator's current element?

for example if `c.next()` returned `'c'`, it means that iterator was at `'b'` before. Is there a way I can get `'b'` without using `next()`?

Comment: A few non-builtin `itertools.cycle` operations are posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442656/2707864).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831549/get-matplotlib-color-cycle-state

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators/generators don't have any way to get the current value. You should either keep a reference to it or create some wrapper that holds onto it for you.

Comment: This can be done, even without changing the current state, see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59442656/2707864)

Answer (score 2):

***Note: This only works if there are no repeated elements.***
Whether this is a serious practical limitation depends on each one's use.
In my case, most of the `itertools.cycle` I have worked with fall under this category.

One can actually get the current state of a `cycle` with a helper function, and other info as well.
It actually uses `next`, but this is transparent to the caller.

```
import itertools 

def get_cycle_props(cycle) :
    """Get the properties (elements, length, current state) of a cycle, without advancing it"""
    # Get the current state
    partial = []
    n = 0
    g = next(cycle)
    while ( g not in partial ) :
        partial.append(g)
        g = next(cycle)
        n += 1
    # Cycle until the "current" (now previous) state
    for i in range(n-1) :
        g = next(cycle)
    return (partial, n, partial[0])

def get_cycle_list(cycle) :
    """Get the elements of a cycle, without advancing it"""
    return get_cycle_props(cycle)[0]

def get_cycle_state(cycle) :
    """Get the current state of a cycle, without advancing it"""
    return get_cycle_props(cycle)[2]

def get_cycle_len(cycle) :
    """Get the length of a cycle, without advancing it"""
    return get_cycle_props(cycle)[1]

# initialize list 
test_list = [3, 4, 5, 7, 1] 
c = itertools.cycle(test_list)
print('cycle state =', get_cycle_state(c))
print('cycle length =', get_cycle_len(c))
print('cycle list =', get_cycle_list(c))
next(c)
print('cycle state =', get_cycle_state(c))
print('cycle length =', get_cycle_len(c))
print('cycle list =', get_cycle_list(c))
```

produces the following output

```
cycle state = 3
cycle length = 5
cycle list = [3, 4, 5, 7, 1]
cycle state = 4
cycle length = 5
cycle list = [4, 5, 7, 1, 3]
```

---

This can actually be taken advantage of to "rewind" a cycle, with the function

```
def shift_cycle(cycle, npos=0) :
    """Shift a cycle, a given number of positions (can be negative)."""
    (cycle_list, nelem, curr_state) = get_cycle_props(cycle)
    for i in range(nelem+npos) :
        g = next(cycle)
    return
```

Try

```
shift_cycle(c, -2)
print('cycle state =', get_cycle_state(c))
```

Comment: The "Note" at the bottom should be highlighted a little more prominently imo, that's a pretty large caveat. This will fail for something as simple as `[1, 1, 2]`.

Comment: @cs95 - Already emphasized... Whether this is a serious practical limitation depends on each one's use. In my case, most of the `itertools.cycle` I have worked with fall under this category, so it would work neatly.