# Twinx/Secondary-y: Do not start with first color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a color scheme that comes from

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

so **I don't want to manually pick colors, or pick them from a color cycler**. However, when I have a secondary axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.plot(np.array([1, 2]))
ax2.plot(np.array([3, 4]))
```

It will plot both lines in the same color. How do I tell `ax2` that there is already `n=1` lines drawn on that plot, such that it starts with the `n+1`th color?

Comment: *"How do I tell ax2 that there is already n=1 lines drawn on that axis"* There is no line drawn on `ax2` yet, so it chooses the first color of the colorcycle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think manually calling `next()` on the `prop_cycler` as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50701379/1221661) is a bit error prone because it's easy to forget. In order to automate the process, you can make both axes share the same cycler:

```
ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler
```

Yes, it is still an ugly hack because it depends on the internal implementation details instead of a defined interface. But in the absence of an official feature, this is probably the most robust solution. As you can see, you can add plots on the two axes in any order, without manual intervention.

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler = ax1._get_lines.prop_cycler

ax1.plot(np.array([1, 2, 3]))
ax2.plot(np.array([3, 5, 4]))
ax1.plot(np.array([0, 1, 3]))
ax2.plot(np.array([2, 4, 1]))

plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot]

Answer (score 3):

There is unfortunately no "recommended" way to manipulate the cycler state. See some in-depth discussion at [Get matplotlib color cycle state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831549/get-matplotlib-color-cycle-state).

You may however access the current cycler and advance it manually.

```
next(ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler)
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.plot(np.array([1, 2, 3]))

next(ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler)
ax2.plot(np.array([3, 5,4]))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `.next()` doesnt work for me, but `ax2._get_lines.prop_cycler.__next__()` does.

Comment: Good point, `.next()` is python 2 only. I updated the answer with what works in any version.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot an empty list to `ax2` before plotting your actual data.  This causes the first colour in the cycle to be used to draw a line that doesn't really exist, moving on to the second colour for the real data.

```
plt.style.use("ggplot")
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax.plot(np.array([1, 2]))

ax2.plot([])  # Plotting nothing.

ax2.plot(np.array([2, 1]))
```

[image: Plotting nothing to skip a colour]