# hist and axvline do not follow color cycle / matplotlib style

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a distribution and it's mean:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('ggplot')

numbers = np.random.rand(100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(numbers)
ax.axvline(numbers.mean())
```

which will plot a red line on top of a red distribution. Importantly, I want to use the colors from my color scheme (`gglot`), and hence I do not want to manually select colors, or even a color cycle.

[Recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50701379/1082349), I learned that if I want to "force" the color cycler to use the next color, I can do

```
next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)
```

However, adding that line in between the hist and axvline does not help here. How could I "force" `hist` and `axvline` to follow the colors from my style?

Comment: Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33608574/5851928) in between `hist` and `axvline` works for me

Comment: @DavidG sorry, what exactly works?

Comment: Are you trying to get `axvline` to use the next color in the color cycle?

Comment: I have the same issue.  `axvline` doesn't honor the style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the next color in the cycle by using

```
next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color']
```

You then need to explicitly use this in the `color=` argument of `axvline`:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

numbers = np.random.rand(100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(numbers)

ax.axvline(numbers.mean(), color = next(ax._get_lines.prop_cycler)['color'])

plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: looks like a bug to me