# How to cycle through colors in a plot for each iteration of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, colors

I am trying to run a for loop that cycles through colours for each iteration of a for loop. I am finding similar questions that cycle through colours but not one that is dependent on a particular for loop. I provide some links below:

[How to pick a new color for each plotted line within a figure in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971269/how-to-pick-a-new-color-for-each-plotted-line-within-a-figure-in-matplotlib)

[`matplotlib.cycler`](https://matplotlib.org/cycler/)

[Color cycler demo](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/color_cycle_demo.html)

My code is for a simple random walk

```
# Parameters
ntraj=10
n=20
p=0.4

# Initialize holder for trajectories
xtraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)

# Simulation
for j in range(ntraj):
    for i in range(n):
        xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+2.0*np.random.binomial(1,p)-1.0

    plt.plot(range(n+1),xtraj,'b-',alpha=0.2)
plt.title("Simple Random Walk")
```

I would like to create a line with a different colour for each `j`. I apologize if the answer is obvious. I am a novice at python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Choose any colour palette you like from [`matplotlib.cm`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#miscellaneous)

Try:

```
# Parameters
ntraj=10
n=20
p=0.4

colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,ntraj))# Initialize holder for trajectories
xtraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)


# Simulation
for j in range(ntraj):
    for i in range(n):
        xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+2.0*np.random.binomial(1,p)-1.0

    plt.plot(range(n+1),xtraj,'b-',alpha=0.2, color=colors[j])

plt.title("Simple Random Walk")
```

[image]

Comment: Yoou can inc the thickness of line by linewidth in plt.plot... better use `linewidth=2.0`

Answer (score 6):

I added a list of colors. I'm pretty sure they can be RGB or Hex. Then inside the j loop the color will switch to the next index.

```
colors = ['b','g','r','c','m','y']
# Parameters

# Simulation
for j in range(ntraj):
    color = colors[j % len(colors)]
    for i in range(n):
        xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+2.0*np.random.binomial(1,p)-1.0

    plt.plot(range(n+1),xtraj,"{}-".format(color),alpha=0.2)
plt.title("Simple Random Walk")
```

Answer (score 5):

As it is now, new colour will be taken for each line. If you want to limit choices and loop through a list you can use `itertools.cycle`:

```
from itertools import cycle

colours = cycle(['red', 'green', 'blue'])


# Simulation
for j in range(ntraj):
    for i in range(n):
        xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+2.0*np.random.binomial(1,p)-1.0

    plt.plot(range(n+1),xtraj,'b-',alpha=0.2, color=colours.next())
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey_Mints this works well if trying to cycle through colours.

Comment: This answer has since dated, use `next(colors)` instead of `colors.next()` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5237664

Answer (score 3):

You have several options using matplotlib.pylplot.

Besides the already provided solutions, you can define your color directly and change the values depending on your for loop:

```
 # Parameters
ntraj=10
n=20
p=0.4

xtraj=np.zeros(n+1,float)


# Simulation
for j in range(ntraj):
    for i in range(n):
        xtraj[i+1]=xtraj[i]+2.0*np.random.binomial(1,p)-1.0

    ctemp = 0.1+(j-1)/ntraj
    plt.plot(range(n+1),xtraj,'b-',alpha=0.2, color=(ctemp, ctemp, ctemp))

plt.title("Simple Random Walk")
```