# How to build a SystemTray app for Windows?

Tags: python, windows, macos, desktop-application, appcelerator

I usually work on a Linux system, but I have a situation where I need to write a client app that would run on windows as a service. Can someone help me or direct, on how to build a system tray app (for example like dropbox) for the windows environment, which gets started on OS startup and the icon sits in the TaskBar and on clicking the app icon presents a menu.

My scripting language is python. Thanks.

Comment: It's called the notification area, not system tray ...

Comment: @Joey: I've seen it called both: http://kb.iu.edu/data/aiat.html . Technically you seem to be correct though.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You do this using the  [pywin32 (Python for Windows Extensions)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module.

[Example Code for Python 2](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085694/whats-the-simplest-way-to-put-a-python-script-into-the-system-tray-windows)

To make it run at startup you could mess around with services but it's actually much easier to install a link to the exe in the users "Startup Folder".

**Windows 7 and Vista**

c:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

**Windows XP**

c:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Answer (score 29):

There are (at least) a couple of libraries openly available for this now:

- [pystray](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray)
- [infi.systray](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.systray)

I just started using `infi.systray` in a project, and it's worked well for me. Here's how little code you need to do something very basic (taken from their docs):

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
def say_hello(systray):
    print("Hello, World!")
menu_options = (("Say Hello", None, say_hello),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("icon.ico", "Example tray icon", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

Answer (score 28):

I modified the `SysTrayIcon.py` [Python 2 script](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html) to work in **Python 3**

- You need to install `pip install pywin32`.
- After that you need to run `python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install` from your Python directory to register the dlls.
- For the test script to run, you need to have some *.ico files in your working directory - you can find lots of them in your c:\windows* folders (search for `file:.ico`).
- To hide the program, you can run it via `pythonw.exe`.
- If you need balloon notifications, have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42085439/2441026 (`Plyer` package).
- To have a menu with only the Quit button you need to pass `menu_options = ((None, None, None),)` - (or change the class to not always append menu_options).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Module     : SysTrayIcon.py
# Synopsis   : Windows System tray icon.
# Programmer : Simon Brunning - simon@brunningonline.net - modified for Python 3
# Date       : 13 February 2018
# Notes      : Based on (i.e. ripped off from) Mark Hammond's
#              win32gui_taskbar.py and win32gui_menu.py demos from PyWin32
'''TODO

For now, the demo at the bottom shows how to use it...'''

import os
import sys
import win32api         # package pywin32
import win32con
import win32gui_struct
try:
    import winxpgui as win32gui
except ImportError:
    import win32gui

class SysTrayIcon(object):
    '''TODO'''
    QUIT = 'QUIT'
    SPECIAL_ACTIONS = [QUIT]

    FIRST_ID = 1023

    def __init__(self,
                 icon,
                 hover_text,
                 menu_options,
                 on_quit=None,
                 default_menu_index=None,
                 window_class_name=None,):

        self.icon = icon
        self.hover_text = hover_text
        self.on_quit = on_quit

        menu_options = menu_options + (('Quit', None, self.QUIT),)
        self._next_action_id = self.FIRST_ID
        self.menu_actions_by_id = set()
        self.menu_options = self._add_ids_to_menu_options(list(menu_options))
        self.menu_actions_by_id = dict(self.menu_actions_by_id)
        del self._next_action_id


        self.default_menu_index = (default_menu_index or 0)
        self.window_class_name = window_class_name or "SysTrayIconPy"

        message_map = {win32gui.RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarCreated"): self.restart,
                       win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.destroy,
                       win32con.WM_COMMAND: self.command,
                       win32con.WM_USER+20 : self.notify,}
        # Register the Window class.
        window_class = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        hinst = window_class.hInstance = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        window_class.lpszClassName = self.window_class_name
        window_class.style = win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW;
        window_class.hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
        window_class.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW
        window_class.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(window_class)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(classAtom,
                                          self.window_class_name,
                                          style,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          hinst,
                                          None)
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        self.notify_id = None
        self.refresh_icon()

        win32gui.PumpMessages()

    def _add_ids_to_menu_options(self, menu_options):
        result = []
        for menu_option in menu_options:
            option_text, option_icon, option_action = menu_option
            if callable(option_action) or option_action in self.SPECIAL_ACTIONS:
                self.menu_actions_by_id.add((self._next_action_id, option_action))
                result.append(menu_option + (self._next_action_id,))
            elif non_string_iterable(option_action):
                result.append((option_text,
                               option_icon,
                               self._add_ids_to_menu_options(option_action),
                               self._next_action_id))
            else:
                print('Unknown item', option_text, option_icon, option_action)
            self._next_action_id += 1
        return result

    def refresh_icon(self):
        # Try and find a custom icon
        hinst = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        if os.path.isfile(self.icon):
            icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
            hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst,
                                       self.icon,
                                       win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       icon_flags)
        else:
            print("Can't find icon file - using default.")
            hicon = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)

        if self.notify_id: message = win32gui.NIM_MODIFY
        else: message = win32gui.NIM_ADD
        self.notify_id = (self.hwnd,
                          0,
                          win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP,
                          win32con.WM_USER+20,
                          hicon,
                          self.hover_text)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(message, self.notify_id)

    def restart(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        self.refresh_icon()

    def destroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if self.on_quit: self.on_quit(self)
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_DELETE, nid)
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

    def notify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            self.execute_menu_option(self.default_menu_index + self.FIRST_ID)
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP:
            self.show_menu()
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP:
            pass
        return True

    def show_menu(self):
        menu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
        self.create_menu(menu, self.menu_options)
        #win32gui.SetMenuDefaultItem(menu, 1000, 0)

        pos = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
        # See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/menus_0hdi.asp
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.hwnd)
        win32gui.TrackPopupMenu(menu,
                                win32con.TPM_LEFTALIGN,
                                pos[0],
                                pos[1],
                                0,
                                self.hwnd,
                                None)
        win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_NULL, 0, 0)

    def create_menu(self, menu, menu_options):
        for option_text, option_icon, option_action, option_id in menu_options[::-1]:
            if option_icon:
                option_icon = self.prep_menu_icon(option_icon)

            if option_id in self.menu_actions_by_id:                
                item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=option_text,
                                                                hbmpItem=option_icon,
                                                                wID=option_id)
                win32gui.InsertMenuItem(menu, 0, 1, item)
            else:
                submenu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
                self.create_menu(submenu, option_action)
                item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=option_text,
                                                                hbmpItem=option_icon,
                                                                hSubMenu=submenu)
                win32gui.InsertMenuItem(menu, 0, 1, item)

    def prep_menu_icon(self, icon):
        # First load the icon.
        ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSMICON)
        ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSMICON)
        hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(0, icon, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, ico_x, ico_y, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)

        hdcBitmap = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(0)
        hdcScreen = win32gui.GetDC(0)
        hbm = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, ico_x, ico_y)
        hbmOld = win32gui.SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbm)
        # Fill the background.
        brush = win32gui.GetSysColorBrush(win32con.COLOR_MENU)
        win32gui.FillRect(hdcBitmap, (0, 0, 16, 16), brush)
        # unclear if brush needs to be feed.  Best clue I can find is:
        # "GetSysColorBrush returns a cached brush instead of allocating a new
        # one." - implies no DeleteObject
        # draw the icon
        win32gui.DrawIconEx(hdcBitmap, 0, 0, hicon, ico_x, ico_y, 0, 0, win32con.DI_NORMAL)
        win32gui.SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbmOld)
        win32gui.DeleteDC(hdcBitmap)

        return hbm

    def command(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        id = win32gui.LOWORD(wparam)
        self.execute_menu_option(id)

    def execute_menu_option(self, id):
        menu_action = self.menu_actions_by_id[id]      
        if menu_action == self.QUIT:
            win32gui.DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        else:
            menu_action(self)

def non_string_iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return not isinstance(obj, str)

# Minimal self test. You'll need a bunch of ICO files in the current working
# directory in order for this to work...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import itertools, glob

    icons = itertools.cycle(glob.glob('*.ico'))
    hover_text = "SysTrayIcon.py Demo"
    def hello(sysTrayIcon): print("Hello World.")
    def simon(sysTrayIcon): print("Hello Simon.")
    def switch_icon(sysTrayIcon):
        sysTrayIcon.icon = next(icons)
        sysTrayIcon.refresh_icon()
    menu_options = (('Say Hello', next(icons), hello),
                    ('Switch Icon', None, switch_icon),
                    ('A sub-menu', next(icons), (('Say Hello to Simon', next(icons), simon),
                                                  ('Switch Icon', next(icons), switch_icon),
                                                 ))
                   )
    def bye(sysTrayIcon): print('Bye, then.')

    SysTrayIcon(next(icons), hover_text, menu_options, on_quit=bye, default_menu_index=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried and it shows the icon. But when I run my main program from the menu icon, the right-click doesn't work anymore. I see my main program running, but impossible to show anymore the menu by right-clicking? DO you have any idea of this issue? Or is it normal, .... it is just waiting my main program end before the systray menu show up again by right clicking?

Comment: For the icon to reappear after the the taskbar restarted (kill explorer.exe and restart it) the restart-function has to be changed like that:    
def restart(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        # Set notify_id to None so the icon will be added instead of modified
        self.notify_id = None
        self.refresh_icon()

Answer (score 6):

I also modified `sysTrayIcon.py` to work in python 3 but no prerequisites are needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Module     : SysTrayIcon.py
# Synopsis   : Windows System tray icon.
# Programmer : Simon Brunning - simon@brunningonline.net
# Date       : 11 April 2005
# Notes      : Based on (i.e. ripped off from) Mark Hammond's
#              win32gui_taskbar.py and win32gui_menu.py demos from PyWin32
'''TODO

For now, the demo at the bottom shows how to use it...'''
         
import os
import sys
import win32api
import win32con
import win32gui_struct
try:
    import winxpgui as win32gui
except ImportError:
    import win32gui

class SysTrayIcon(object):
    '''TODO'''
    QUIT = 'QUIT'
    SPECIAL_ACTIONS = [QUIT]
    
    FIRST_ID = 1023
    
    def __init__(self,
                 icon,
                 hover_text,
                 menu_options,
                 on_quit=None,
                 default_menu_index=None,
                 window_class_name=None,):
        
        self.icon = icon
        self.hover_text = hover_text
        self.on_quit = on_quit
        
        menu_options = menu_options + (('Quit', None, self.QUIT),)
        self._next_action_id = self.FIRST_ID
        self.menu_actions_by_id = set()
        self.menu_options = self._add_ids_to_menu_options(list(menu_options))
        self.menu_actions_by_id = dict(self.menu_actions_by_id)
        del self._next_action_id
        
        
        self.default_menu_index = (default_menu_index or 0)
        self.window_class_name = window_class_name or "SysTrayIconPy"
        
        message_map = {win32gui.RegisterWindowMessage("TaskbarCreated"): self.restart,
                       win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.destroy,
                       win32con.WM_COMMAND: self.command,
                       win32con.WM_USER+20 : self.notify,}
        # Register the Window class.
        window_class = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        hinst = window_class.hInstance = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        window_class.lpszClassName = self.window_class_name
        window_class.style = win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW;
        window_class.hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
        window_class.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW
        window_class.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(window_class)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(classAtom,
                                          self.window_class_name,
                                          style,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                          0,
                                          0,
                                          hinst,
                                          None)
        win32gui.UpdateWindow(self.hwnd)
        self.notify_id = None
        self.refresh_icon()
        
        win32gui.PumpMessages()

    def _add_ids_to_menu_options(self, menu_options):
        result = []
        for menu_option in menu_options:
            option_text, option_icon, option_action = menu_option
            if callable(option_action) or option_action in self.SPECIAL_ACTIONS:
                self.menu_actions_by_id.add((self._next_action_id, option_action))
                result.append(menu_option + (self._next_action_id,))
            elif non_string_iterable(option_action):
                result.append((option_text,
                               option_icon,
                               self._add_ids_to_menu_options(option_action),
                               self._next_action_id))
            else:
                print('Unknown item', option_text, option_icon, option_action)
            self._next_action_id += 1
        return result
        
    def refresh_icon(self):
        # Try and find a custom icon
        hinst = win32gui.GetModuleHandle(None)
        if os.path.isfile(self.icon):
            icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
            hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(hinst,
                                       self.icon,
                                       win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                                       0,
                                       0,
                                       icon_flags)
        else:
            print("Can't find icon file - using default.")
            hicon = win32gui.LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)

        if self.notify_id: message = win32gui.NIM_MODIFY
        else: message = win32gui.NIM_ADD
        self.notify_id = (self.hwnd,
                          0,
                          win32gui.NIF_ICON | win32gui.NIF_MESSAGE | win32gui.NIF_TIP,
                          win32con.WM_USER+20,
                          hicon,
                          self.hover_text)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(message, self.notify_id)

    def restart(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        self.refresh_icon()

    def destroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if self.on_quit: self.on_quit(self)
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon(win32gui.NIM_DELETE, nid)
        win32gui.PostQuitMessage(0) # Terminate the app.

    def notify(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        if lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
            self.execute_menu_option(self.default_menu_index + self.FIRST_ID)
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_RBUTTONUP:
            self.show_menu()
        elif lparam==win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP:
            pass
        return True
        
    def show_menu(self):
        menu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
        self.create_menu(menu, self.menu_options)
        #win32gui.SetMenuDefaultItem(menu, 1000, 0)
        
        pos = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
        # See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/menus_0hdi.asp
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self.hwnd)
        win32gui.TrackPopupMenu(menu,
                                win32con.TPM_LEFTALIGN,
                                pos[0],
                                pos[1],
                                0,
                                self.hwnd,
                                None)
        win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_NULL, 0, 0)
    
    def create_menu(self, menu, menu_options):
        for option_text, option_icon, option_action, option_id in menu_options[::-1]:
            if option_icon:
                option_icon = self.prep_menu_icon(option_icon)
            
            if option_id in self.menu_actions_by_id:                
                item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=option_text,
                                                                hbmpItem=option_icon,
                                                                wID=option_id)
                win32gui.InsertMenuItem(menu, 0, 1, item)
            else:
                submenu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
                self.create_menu(submenu, option_action)
                item, extras = win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO(text=option_text,
                                                                hbmpItem=option_icon,
                                                                hSubMenu=submenu)
                win32gui.InsertMenuItem(menu, 0, 1, item)

    def prep_menu_icon(self, icon):
        # First load the icon.
        ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXSMICON)
        ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYSMICON)
        hicon = win32gui.LoadImage(0, icon, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, ico_x, ico_y, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)

        hdcBitmap = win32gui.CreateCompatibleDC(0)
        hdcScreen = win32gui.GetDC(0)
        hbm = win32gui.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, ico_x, ico_y)
        hbmOld = win32gui.SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbm)
        # Fill the background.
        brush = win32gui.GetSysColorBrush(win32con.COLOR_MENU)
        win32gui.FillRect(hdcBitmap, (0, 0, 16, 16), brush)
        # unclear if brush needs to be feed.  Best clue I can find is:
        # "GetSysColorBrush returns a cached brush instead of allocating a new
        # one." - implies no DeleteObject
        # draw the icon
        win32gui.DrawIconEx(hdcBitmap, 0, 0, hicon, ico_x, ico_y, 0, 0, win32con.DI_NORMAL)
        win32gui.SelectObject(hdcBitmap, hbmOld)
        win32gui.DeleteDC(hdcBitmap)
        
        return hbm

    def command(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        id = win32gui.LOWORD(wparam)
        self.execute_menu_option(id)
        
    def execute_menu_option(self, id):
        menu_action = self.menu_actions_by_id[id]      
        if menu_action == self.QUIT:
            win32gui.DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        else:
            menu_action(self)
            
def non_string_iterable(obj):
    try:
        iter(obj)
    except TypeError:
        return False
    else:
        return not isinstance(obj, str)

# Minimal self test. You'll need a bunch of ICO files in the current working
# directory in order for this to work...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import itertools, glob
    
    icons = itertools.cycle(glob.glob('*.ico'))
    hover_text = "SysTrayIcon.py Demo"
    def hello(sysTrayIcon): print("Hello World.")
    def simon(sysTrayIcon): print("Hello Simon.")
    def switch_icon(sysTrayIcon):
        sysTrayIcon.icon = next(icons)
        sysTrayIcon.refresh_icon()
    menu_options = (('Say Hello', next(icons), hello),
                    ('Switch Icon', None, switch_icon),
                    ('A sub-menu', next(icons), (('Say Hello to Simon', next(icons), simon),
                                                  ('Switch Icon', next(icons), switch_icon),
                                                 ))
                   )
    def bye(sysTrayIcon): print('Bye, then.')
    
    SysTrayIcon(next(icons), hover_text, menu_options, on_quit=bye, default_menu_index=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

**2022 November Update for anyone still wondering:**

Tried both packages. Both work as intended.

1. [pystray](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray) consumes more RAM than compared to [infi.systray](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.systray).
2. `pystray: 112Mb` vs `infi.systray: 11Mb`
3. infi.systray works with Python 3 (Using Python 3.9.1)
4. infi.systray only supports Windows.
5. pystray supports Linux under Xorg, GNOME and Ubuntu, macOS and Windows

**Examples:** `(Used this code for noting the RAM usage)`

**infi.systray:**

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon

def say_hello(systray):
    print ("Hello")
    
menu_options = (("Say Hello", None, say_hello),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("icon.ico", "Example tray icon", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

**pystray:**

```
import pystray
import PIL.Image

def on_clicked(icon, item):
    print("Hello")

image = PIL.Image.open("icon.png")
tray = pystray.Icon("Tray", image, menu=pystray.Menu(
    pystray.MenuItem("Button-1", on_clicked)
))
tray.run()
```

Disclaimer: I have not tried every function/feature that the packages offer. Just wanted to share my findings