# How to create notifications in windows through python bound to an existing win32py task bar utility?

Tags: python, windows, windows-10, pywin32

There are a few answers floating around about about how to create windows notifications in python ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows)). Each one of those creates their own little taskbar utility, spawns the notifications, then kills the utility once the notification is finished.

I have a windows taskbar utility heavily based on the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494739/how-to-build-a-systemtray-app-for-windows).

I am curious how someone would add notification functionality that is bound to the existing taskbar utility (using pywin32 and not an external module). Admittedly I am not super comfortable with win32py code so if you could break down how it works that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `win10totast` module(you should install it firstly).

Here is an example:

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast(u'Title', u'You have receive a notice.',icon_path=None,duration=3,threaded=False)
```

Read more about [this module](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications)

Comment: Apologies, I have used win10toast (i was not clear on this front). This is more of a thought exercise at this point on how one might create your own notifications instead of relying on a module like this one.