# How to make a python EXE run in the background?

Tags: python, windows, exe

I made a python EXE to test servers and change a file if a server is down but I have a big problem right now, the exe is running fine but it`s always opened I tried to use pyc and it worked but this program is going to be used by the whole company, so I need a exe that if you minimize it will appear just on the right side of the taskbar.
[image: I need the program to just appear here]

and the other problem is that I need to make this program work everytime the user log`s in their laptop, but I do not have any idea of how to make this

the program right now it`s running like this
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a SystemTray app for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494739/how-to-build-a-systemtray-app-for-windows)

Comment: there maybe some sort of "run quiet" option that runs without opening a cmd window. Also, i'd use windows task scheduler to run at login

Comment: @jordanm it answers one of them, thanks!

Comment: @SuperStew widows task scheduler can be used for exes?

Comment: Currently there's no high-level option in Explorer to run console applications without allocating a console session (which has nothing to do with the CMD shell, except that "cmd.exe" is also a console application, just like "python.exe"), or to allocate a console session with no window or a hidden window. This process startup behavior can only be controlled at a low level when calling `CreateProcessW`. That said, Python has non-console binaries named "pythonw.exe" and "pyw.exe" just for this purpose, and the default file association for ".pyw" scripts should use one of those.