# Minimise Python to System Tray and Generate Notifications?

Tags: python, python-2.7, notifications, system-tray, minimize

I've had a look around but haven't been able to find anything to get close to doing what I want.

I want to make my Python script launch as a minimised system tray application or have the ability to minimise to system tray and also have the ability to make system tray notifications

Any one have any ideas/libraries or examples?

Thanks
- Hyflex

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085694/whats-the-simplest-way-to-put-a-python-script-into-the-system-tray-windows

Comment: Thanks for that, such a simple change to get it going >_<

Now I've got to find something for notifications

Comment: See also: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921203/how-to-create-a-system-tray-popup-message-with-python-windows

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx).

Then 
as our friends here suggested in the comments , you could use [SysTrayIcon.py](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/SysTrayIcon.py.html) to show your application in a system tray .

As of displaying notifications you should check [Win32 Python Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) which has an example in `Lib\site-packages\win32\demos\win32gui_menu.py` . that should help you get started .